# Rails 4 only routing to Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok so i'm having an issue. I'm creating a blog like application into my existing application. I setup up in my routes.rb a route for my posts like below:

```
#config/routes.rb

get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#index'
resources :posts
```

So i have all my files in my views such as:

```
index.html.erb
edit.html.erb
show.html.erb
new.html.erb
_form.html
```

So now when I got localhost:3000/posts/new I get a blank page where my edit.html.erb should have loaded my _form.html. Watching the Rails Server Console the server is not rendering 'posts/new.html.erb' it's rendering 'posts/index.html.erb'. It renders 'post/index.html.erb' regardless of what page I try to visit. Any advice here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes you put...

```
get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#index'
```

first.  This means that pretty much all other GET routes, like `posts/new` will match against the `posts/:id` (the `id` will be "new")

I would just remove that line.  The `resources :posts` will map `posts/:id` to `posts#show` which is where it really belongs.

Comment: Thank you. I thought both were needed. I thought the resources :posts was giving me access to the controllers methods only